# Qt Creator "override method" shortcut?

Tags: c++, overriding, qt-creator

Does Qt Creator have a "override method" shortcut like eclipse?

For those who don't know eclipse, there is a context menu "Source > Override Method" that show a dialog. Check the method you want to override, and it will generate stubs for those method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest that is available under QtCreator is `Add Definition to *cpp`. So say you have a declaration of `void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)` in the header file, than if you select the function and pop the context menu under `Refactor` there is an option `Add Definition to cpp`

Comment: There's still no shortcut available for it yet, unfortunately: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-3715

Answer (score 28):

1. right click on the **class name**
2. from context menu, select **Refactor** -> **Insert Virtual Functions of Base Classes**

btw, I'm using Qt Creator 3.4.1.

Comment: It would be more awesome with some actual code snippets.